# Duplicate configurable products in Magento programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, duplicate

I want to duplicate configurable Products with their associated products programmatically in Magento. Can anyone help regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
$productId = 2;

//Load configurable product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

//Getting children ids
$childs = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getChildrenIds($productId);

$newChildIds = array();
foreach ($childs as $childId) {
    //duplicate child products
    $newChildProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($childId)->duplicate();
    $newChildIds[] = $newChildProduct->getId();
}

//Duplicate configurable product
$newProduct = $product->duplicate();

//Attach simple products to new configurable
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->saveProducts($newProduct, $newChildIds);
```

But after duplication of product, new product will be disabled and without SKU. You can enable it and generate SKU for new product added this code:

```
$newProduct->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setSku('new_sku');

$newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);
```

**EDIT**

Try this code for copying attributes (it save attributes):

```
//Get product attributes
$usedProductAttributeIds = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductAttributeIds();
$configurableAttributesData = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();

//Remove some items from attributes
foreach ($configurableAttributesData as $key => $data) {
    unset($configurableAttributesData[$key]['id'], $configurableAttributesData[$key]['values'][0]['value_index']);
}
```

And after all operations with new product add this code:

```
$newProductId = $newProduct->getId();

//I dont know, but product must be reloaded.
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($newProductId);    

//Set all attributes
$newProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($usedProductAttributeIds);
$newProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
$newProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);

$newProduct->save();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Irop, But how to set the attributes for the Duplicated base product.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that attributes are missing. I'm updated answer. It work for me

Comment: HI Irop, Do you have any Idea on Duplicating the Bundle products with their Items.

Comment: I duplicated bundle products earlier and i use just `$product->duplicate();` and its copy all products data with their items. It does not work for you?

Comment: When I use `$product->duplicate(); ` it duplicating only the Base product not the bundled items.

Comment: Great answer! Only one fix (at least for Magento 1.9): foreach ($childs[0] as $childId)

Comment: The child array contains another array inside of it, so I had to put the index 0