# Clone Configureable Product with all its simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product

Is there any way to clone/copy a conf. product with all its simple products without needing to use code/coding?

Comment: This may help you [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116108/duplicate-configurable-products-in-magento-programmatically](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116108/duplicate-configurable-products-in-magento-programmatically)

Comment: In **Magento1** for configuration product Can i clone it's associative products too? right now it just clones configurable product and it's attributes like size and color but it's simple products.. any suggestions??

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151020)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Go to **Catalog|Manage Product**

[image: Catalog|Manage Product]

Select the product you want to copy.

[image: Edit Product]

Now click on **Duplicate** on the right upper corner.

[image: Duplicate button]

Hope this help you.

Comment: Could you please send a Screenshot of this? Because I can't seem to find the duplicate button

Comment: I just edit my response with the images you request. Tell me if anything else is needed.

Comment: @Nicklas You should mark this answer as accepted (click the big tick on the left near the up/down & score area) if it's the correct answer.